# mixing multiple tables into one

Tags: mysql, join, union

I reckon what i want has something to do with ***union*** and/or ***join*** but i couldnt figure out how to do it so far so this is me asking for help.

I have some tables with different data but exact same structure and i wanna mix em up into one. Lets say i have 2 tables like those.

Store_1

```
Product      Quantity
--------     ----------
AAA          25
BBB          15
```

Store_2

```
Product      Quantity
--------     ----------
AAA          10
CCC          40
```

What i want as a mix of those two tables is this :

```
Product      Store_1_Quantity     Store_2_Quantity
--------     ----------------     ----------------
AAA          25                   10
BBB          15                   Null / 0
CCC          Null / 0             40
```

And this is not limited to just two tables. Actually for some instances i need to mix 10 tables into one so any ideas?

Comment: try to use cross join

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need both **UNION** and **LEFT JOINs**. Try this:

```
SELECT p.*, store_1.quantity AS Store_1_Quantity, store_2.quantity AS Store_2_Quantity
FROM (SELECT Product FROM Store_1 UNION SELECT Product FROM Store_2) AS p
LEFT JOIN Store_1
ON p.product = Store_1.product
LEFT JOIN Store_2
ON p.product = Store_2.product
```

Working Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8f4bc1/3

Comment: Thx for the quick response mate. So if need to add one or more store to the query something like this does the job.  `SELECT p.*, store_1.quantity AS Store_1_Quantity, store_2.quantity AS Store_2_Quantity, store_3.quantity AS Store_3_Quantity
FROM (SELECT Product FROM Store_1 UNION SELECT Product FROM Store_2  UNION SELECT Product FROM Store_3) AS p
LEFT JOIN Store_1
ON p.product = Store_1.product
LEFT JOIN Store_2
ON p.product = Store_2.product
LEFT JOIN Store_3
ON p.product = Store_3.product`  
I guess this is the right way to do to expand your code for more stores, right?

Comment: @BatuZet yes you are correct, this is the way to add more stores.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a [full outer join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Full_outer_join).  Problem is MySQL does not support them natively but, they can be [emulated quite easily](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/qrytip.php?id=690) using left and right joins.

For your situation, the following query should work:

```
SELECT A.PRODUCT, A.QUANTITY, B.QUANTITY FROM STORE_1 A
LEFT JOIN STORE_2 B ON (A.PRODUCT = B.PRODUCT)
UNION ALL
SELECT B.PRODUCT, A.QUANTITY, B.QUANTITY FROM STORE_1 A
RIGHT JOIN STORE_2 B ON (A.PRODUCT = B.PRODUCT)
WHERE A.PRODUCT IS NULL;
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response mate, it works like a charm but how about adding one or more stores? How to handle if i have a "Store_3" and even a "Store_4" too?